# Subsetting within a for loop in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, subset

One quick question please: I am trying to compare the values of two columns in `R`. If I do it manually, it works perfectly well. If I use the for loop below, it doesn't work.

Any guidance on why this is happening will be greatly appreciated.

Fernando

```
#Done Manually:

accuracies <- c(
mean (predictions[,1] == mnist_27$test$y),
mean (predictions[,2] == mnist_27$test$y),
mean (predictions[,3] == mnist_27$test$y),
mean (predictions[,4] == mnist_27$test$y),
mean (predictions[,5] == mnist_27$test$y),
mean (predictions[,6] == mnist_27$test$y),
mean (predictions[,7] == mnist_27$test$y),
mean (predictions[,8] == mnist_27$test$y),
mean (predictions[,9] == mnist_27$test$y),
mean (predictions[,10] == mnist_27$test$y))

#Done with the for loop:

accuracies <- for (i in 1:10) {
  mean (predictions[,i] == mnist_27$test$y)  
}
```

Comment: [What Do You Mean “It Doesn't Work”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616)? Errors? Undesired results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we want to use a `for` loop.  Initialize a NULL object and then concatenate the object on each iteration while updating it

```
v1 <- c()
for (i in 1:ncol(predictions)) {
   v1 <- c(v1, mean (predictions[,i] == mnist_27$test$y))

 }
```

Or another option is to initialize the vector with the `length` as the `ncol` of 'predictions' and then use indexing to assign the `mean` values to each element of 'v1'

```
v1 <- numeric(ncol(predictions))
for(i in 1:ncol(predictions)) {
        v1[i] <-  mean (predictions[,i] == mnist_27$test$y)
 }
```

---

In `R`, this can be done more easily with

```
colMeans(predictions == mnist_27$test$y)
```

---

## Benchmark

```r
predictions <- as.data.frame(rep(rnorm(10000), 10))
y<- c(predictions[1:1000,]) 

dyn.vect <- function(){
    v1 <- c()
    for (i in 1:ncol(predictions)) v1 <- c(v1, mean (predictions[,i] == y))
    v1
} 
vector.initialised <- function(){
    v1 <- numeric(ncol(predictions))
    for(i in 1:ncol(predictions)) v1[i] <-  mean (predictions[,i] == y)
    v1
}

( bench<-microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    "Dynamic vector"=dyn.vect(),
    "Intialised vector"=vector.initialised() ,
    colMeans=colMeans(predictions == y),
    lapply=lapply(predictions, function(x) {mean(x==y)})#,
    #times=1000
) )
#> Unit: microseconds
#>               expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
#>     Dynamic vector  270.199  481.5680  627.9717  504.5865  557.5565  8212.167   100
#>  Intialised vector  273.730  480.0315  700.2607  511.1460  570.0820  6879.310   100
#>           colMeans 4450.484 7392.6910 8642.0002 7635.3505 8634.2050 50261.697   100
#>             lapply  272.007  466.1775  565.0209  486.5720  550.4960  4921.402   100
ggplot2::autoplot(bench)
```

[image]
`lapply` seems to be the fastest while `colMeans` seems to be the slowest